# Using a function in NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: objective-c, exception, react-native, uncaught-exception

I want to reference some state in a NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler, and so don't want to pass in a function but a method instead.  But how??  The state I need to reference is a callback from a react native app.  So far i have:

```
#import "RNUncaughtExceptionReporter.h"


@implementation RNUncaughtExceptionReporter

- (dispatch_queue_t)methodQueue
{
    return dispatch_get_main_queue();
}
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(listen:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)listener)
{
    callback = listener;
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(/* what goes here? */);
}

- (void) unhandledExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
    callback(@[@"something went wrong..."]);// todo: send the detail of the exception
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

try this ！

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler (&UncaughtExceptionHandler);


void UncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException* exception)
{
   /* do anything u want with the exception */
}
```